# Oracle SQL Checking for updates based on independent timestamps

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have 2 tables which are related. Both tables both have timestamps. Here is the basic structure of the tables. A Group can have many Group_Members. The Group and Group_Member are related by the group_id.  I have written a query which works great for loading groups and their members. However, I discovered that when Group information changes, it's last_updated column will be updated but the affected Group_Member timestamps will not be updated. Also, when a Group_Member information is updated its last_updated timestamp will be updated, but the Group last_updated timestamp will not be updated. This presents a dilemma for me because I need to check for changes for both Group and Group_Member. If the last_updated timestamp is not updated and I do a left join on both tables, I might not get any results back if the Group_Member changes but its parent Group last_updated timestamp did not. Is there a way to do a search combining both timestamps, even if only one changes and not the other? I have formulated a query below on how I think it should be written. Does this make sense for the situation I explained?

```
      Group( group_id(pk),dept_no, emp_type, last_updated)
      Group_Member(group_id(fk),group_name,join_date, emp_type, last_updated)

        select * from Group grp
        left join Group_Member grp_mbr on grp.group_id=grp_mbr.group_id
        where trunc(grp.last_updated)=trunc(SYSDATE) or 
                     trunc(grp_mbr.last_updated)=trunc(SYSDATE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm astonished you could have a table named "Group" (which is a SQL keyword). Anyway I would suggest the following:

```
SELECT
      *
FROM "Group" grp
LEFT JOIN Group_Member grp_mbr ON grp.group_id = grp_mbr.group_id
      AND grp_mbr.last_updated >= trunc(SYSDATE) AND grp_mbr.last_updated < trunc(SYSDATE) + 1
WHERE grp.last_updated >= trunc(SYSDATE) AND grp.last_updated < trunc(SYSDATE) + 1
OR grp_mbr.group_id IS NOT NULL
```

**Note:** I have removed the use of TRUNC() on the data. Don't do this as it removes the ability of he optimizer to use indexes on those columns. Always adjust the other side of the condition(s) to suit the untouched data (i.e. [Sargable predicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)).

It might be possible for you simplify the query a bit, like this:

```
SELECT
      *
FROM "Group" grp
LEFT JOIN Group_Member grp_mbr ON grp.group_id = grp_mbr.group_id
      AND grp_mbr.last_updated >= trunc(SYSDATE)
WHERE grp.last_updated >= trunc(SYSDATE)
OR grp_mbr.group_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: The table names are actually BOARD AND MEMBER

Comment: I'm unclear about  the WHERE clauses. Could you please explain briefly?

Comment: Also, won't my query return rows that are true for either condition? For example, if grp_mbr.last_updated is updated it will return those rows and if grp.last_updated is updated return those as well?

Comment: Please be aware that updates are not mutually exclusive i.e. group members can be added to a group and group information may change independently, for example, the dept_no changing.